# how can l-values be passed to std::make_pair

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction, forwarding-reference

In `std::make_pair` [there is only one implementation C++14 onwards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)

> template< class T1, class T2 >
> constexpr std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );

Both parameters are R-value references and according to [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/15-2-rvalue-references/)

> R-values references cannot be initialized with l-values.

```
    int i = 1;
    char ch = 'a';
    std::unordered_map<int, char> mp;
    mp.insert(make_pair<int,char>(i, ch));
```

So when I try to use make_pair as in the above code it correctly throws an error `error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'`.

However it works perfectly for the above code if I change drop the template arguments and call it as

```
mp.insert(make_pair(i, ch));
```

I'm confused how this works as `i` and `ch` both are L-values. Does template argument resolution convert L-values to R-values or like how does this work?

Comment: These are not rvalue references - they are [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). They accept both rvalues and lvalues. However, they only work this way if you do **not** specify template parameters explicitly, but allow template parameter deduction to do its job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of `make_pair` are not declared as rvalue-reference, but [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references).

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve
> the value category of a function argument, making it possible to
> forward it by means of std::forward. Forwarding references are either:
>
> 1. function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue
>    reference to cv-unqualified type template parameter of that same
>    function template:

Forwarding referece works with both lvalues and rvalues, with the help of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). When being passed an lvalue, the template parameter would be deduced as lvalue-reference, after reference collapsing, the function parameter is lvalue-reference too. When being passing an rvalue, the template parameter would be deduced as non-reference, the function parameter is rvalue-reference.

On the other hand, if you specify the template argument explicitly like `make_pair<int,char>(...)`, the function parameter become rvalue-reference accordingly.

Comment: In code: `using R = T&; R &&r` declares `r` as `T&`, since `&` + `&&` collapses to `&`. `std::make_pair<T&, U&>` and friends therefore take `(T&, U&)`, not `(T&&, U&&)` or similar. Template argument deduction is designed to choose that specialization when called with lvalues. Calling with rvalues would choose `std::make_pair<T, U>`, which does take `(T&&, U&&)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432202) already explains most of what is going on. I would, though, like to contribute how to make this work with explicit template arguments. You were most of the way there, but didn't take the last step.

> I'm confused how this works as `i` and `ch` both are L-values.

Exactly. You want l-values, which is something you can specify in the template arguments:

```
std::make_pair<int &, char &>(i, ch)
```

or a form that works in more cases:

```
std::make_pair<const int &, const char &>(i, ch)
```

A bit of extra writing, but needed if argument deduction fails for some reason.